# Firebase Appcheck with NextJS SSR?

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

Is it possible to use Firebase AppCheck when I call onRequest Firebase Cloud Functions from NextJS getServerSideProps ?

I'd have to access/create the token from the server side and send it in the header to the cloud function. It seems to be built to only work from the client browser window?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by chatting with Copilot, it was something I've used before and should have thought of it.

The trick, like Firebase Auth and SSR, was to save the token as a cookie and then access it on the server side.